# how to get values in dropdown from print multiple arrays from an array in javascript or typescript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, multidimensional-array

let's see I have an array like `let filterData= [[1,2,3],[x,y],[z,10]]` Have to make it in single line or in single array as an output: `this.filterData= [ 1,2,3,x,y,z,10];`how can I achieve this in Javascript or typescript language.

anyone have a solution of it..please suggest

```
`if (this.data && this.data.length > 0) {
     this.filteredData.push(this.data[index].value);
     this.filteredData.push(this.filteredData);
     console.log(this.filteredData)
   }`
```

Comment: Have you tried `flat()`?

Answer (score 2):

Just using `Array.flat()` can do it

```js
let filterData= [[1,2,3],['x','y'],['z',10]]
filterData = filterData.flat()
console.log(filterData)
```

Comment: Please vote to close duplicates

Comment: @adiga OK,but I just found you have closed it by yourself

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
let filterData= [[1,2,3],["x","y"],["z",10]];
let array=[];
filterData.map((x)=>{x.forEach((m)=>{array.push(m)});})
console.log(array);
```

Comment: What's the point of using `map` if it's being used like `forEach`?